# MS Exchange 2016 CU19 Update Error: The operation failed because UPN value provided for addition/modification is not unique forest-wide

Tags: email, exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2016

I am trying to update exchange to the latest CU.

We have a hybrid setup with O365 and since we barely use the server we have fallen behind on updates.

The last time it was updated was before I was here so I have no direct experience in doing so.

I have read through the docs but I am getting the error below.

We do not have an overly complicated multi-domain AD infrastructure so I believe we should be able to just use the wizard to complete the update and not need to prepare AD ahead of time but I could be wrong.

The error says it is referring to `Install-UserAccount -Name $federatedMailboxId -LastName $federatedMailboxId;`

But I'm not sure exactly which federated mailbox it is referring to.

Hoping someone with experience can point me in the right direction as I am trying to ensure the server is secure against the latest Zero-Day just announced by MS.

Full Error Below:

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
          if (!$RoleIsDatacenter)
          {
            $federatedMailboxId = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Deployment.UpdateRmsSharedIdentity]::SharedIdentityCommonName;
            $federatedEmailUsers = @(Get-User -Filter {LastName -eq $federatedMailboxId} -IgnoreDefaultScope -ResultSize 1);
            if ($federatedEmailUsers.Length -eq 0)
            {
              $federatedEmailUsers = @(Get-User -Arbitration -Filter {LastName -eq $federatedMailboxId} -IgnoreDefaultScope -ResultSize 1);
            }

            if ($federatedEmailUsers.Length -eq 0)
            {
              Install-UserAccount -Name $federatedMailboxId -LastName $federatedMailboxId;
            }
          }
        " was run: "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADConstraintViolationException: An Active Directory Constraint Violation error occurred on XX-XX-XXXX.xxxxxxxx.com. Additional information: The operation failed because UPN value provided for addition/modification is not unique forest-wide.
Active directory response: 000021C8: AtrErr: DSID-03200BE9, #1:
    0: 000021C8: DSID-03200BE9, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 90290 (userPrincipalName)
 ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: A value in the request is invalid.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponse(Int32 messageId, LdapOperation operation, ResultAll resultType, TimeSpan requestTimeOut, Boolean exceptionOnTimeOut)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.GuardedDirectoryExecution.Execute[T](String bucketName, Func`1 action, Int64& concurrency)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.GuardedSendRequest(String forestName, GuardedDirectoryExecution guardedDirectoryExecution, DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan timeout, Func`3 sendRequestDelegate, Int64& concurrency)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, LdapOperation ldapOperation, Nullable`1 clientSideSearchTimeout, IADLogContext logContext, Boolean shouldLogLastFilter)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.ExecuteModificationRequest(ADObject entry, DirectoryRequest request, ADObjectId originalId, Boolean emptyObjectSessionOnException, Boolean isSync)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.AnalyzeDirectoryError(PooledLdapConnection connection, DirectoryRequest request, DirectoryException de, Int32 totalRetries, Int32 retriesOnServer, String callerFilePath, Int32 callerFileLine, String memberName)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.ExecuteModificationRequest(ADObject entry, DirectoryRequest request, ADObjectId originalId, Boolean emptyObjectSessionOnException, Boolean isSync)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.Save(ADObject instanceToSave, IEnumerable`1 properties, Boolean bypassValidation)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADRecipientObjectSession.Save(ADRecipient instanceToSave, String callerFilePath, Int32 callerFileLine, String memberName)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Deployment.InstallUserAccount.InternalProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.<ProcessRecord>b__91_1()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.InvokeRetryableFunc(String funcName, Action func, Boolean terminatePipelineIfFailed)".
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that it is trying to modify the federatedEmail built in user in the AD Users OU. It is not able to do this but it is also not a unique name so it cannot add it. This may be because it is not where it should be or it may be disbaled.

See this article for a bit more info on these accounts.

https://www.azure365pro.com/how-to-recreate-system-mailbox-federatedemail-discoverysearchmailbox-in-exchange-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to check the objects with the same UPN:

```
Get-ADObject -LdapFilter "(userPrincipalName=<UPN>)" -IncludeDeletedObjects
```

Here's a blog on the error "Additional information: The operation failed because UPN value provided for addition/modification is not unique forest-wide." check for more details: [SPN and UPN uniqueness](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/spn-and-upn-uniqueness)